# use api pagination until all the data is fetched in the background

Tags: flutter, api, performance

I have a long list of data coming from database, I'm using pagination and i want to fetch all the list in the background and and view it all instead of viewing page by page.

```
//first using pagination for faster call
var myLongList =[];
 myLongList = await fetchData(pageSize);

//then show all the data when it's ready
fetchData().then((value) {
myLongList.clear();
setState(() {
  myLongList.addAll(value); 
});


});
```

is that a good approach to follow? or there is something better i can try I'm doing this to give a better user experience without the waiting for every search or every new data.

Answer (score 0):

I think loading a lot of data at once is not a good practice, when you have a lot of data I think the best thing to do is to use a lazy list

maybe this can help you.
https://www.kindacode.com/article/flutter-listview-pagination-load-more/

Comment: Sorry if i my question isn't clear but what i meant is that I'm already doing lazy loading and i want to fetch all the data in the background (lazy data is already shown to the user) and when all data is fetched i simply replace the list that contains that some data from lazy loading to the list of all data, and the user doesn't notice.